# Electron auto-updater error: Unable to find latest version on GitHub (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR)

Tags: ssl, electron, ssl-certificate, github-api, electron-builder

I've been trying to pass some configuration for 2 days for this error to stop happening, I really appreciate it if anyone has any idea or possible solution...

I am developing an application that will be made available using electronjs, and will also have an update routine with electron auto update.

The available versions will be found in a private repository on github.

When downloading the executable on a personal machine and trying to fetch an update, there is no problem. The problem occurs when trying to carry out this process within my company's network and ends up giving the error that I will leave as an attachment. (I believe that even on an internal network it should work as we have access to the Github API).

Electron build and publish settings
[image: electron build settings]

The configuration code is a few lines longer than that, but I tried to compress it as much as possible to make it easy to understand the error. When opening the executable, autoUpdater is calling this callback on line 11 with the following message:
[image: code details]

Mensagem:
[2023-09-08T13:43:36.415] [ERROR] cheese - Unable to find latest version on GitHub (https://api.github.com/repos/weg/std-sfm-mes-weg-pointing-releases/releases/latest), please ensure a production release exists: Error: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper. (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:49935)
at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.emit (node:events:513:28)
[2023-09-08T13:43:36.415] [ERROR] cheese - Error in auto-updater.

I can't get out of the error anyway

Comment: your company network might use a forward proxy that inspects HTTPS traffic and present an SSL certificate that your app doesn't trust by default